# How to create subdirectories in android internal storage for images

Tags: android, image, picasso

I am writing an application to store the user profile information and contact information. User profile and contact information also have an image/bitmap. I would like to store images in internal storage probably and display the image using `Picasso` library. I want to application to create a profile directory to store the profile image and similarly for contacts. I want to use `Picasso` to retrieve the image from file and display it on the ImvageView as shown below.

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
       .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
       .load("file:///somepath/profile.png")
       .into(imageView);
```

I am not sure how the application will create sub-directories and store the images. What would be the path for images that can be provided to the `Picasso` to load the image in `Imageview`?

**Edit1**

I think, I can use `getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()` to get the path, but I am still not sure how to create the subdirectories for profile and contacts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Android there is a directory in the internal storage where your app can store any kind of file; you can use [Context.getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) to retrieve it.

You can create subdirectories too, using [File.mkdir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir()). I don't know if Picasso takes care of that, but to be sure you can create the directory beforehand. The code to determine the path  look like this:

```
File makeAndGetProfileDirectory(String profileName) {
    // determine the profile directory
    File profileDirectory = new File(context.getFilesDir(), profileName);

    // creates the directory if not present yet
    profileDirectory.mkdir();

    return profileDirectory;
}
```

Now you can use this method to obtain a directory where to put the profile data, including the picture. Let's say every profile will have a file named `picture.jpg`; the code for Picasso would look like this:

```
String profileName = "foo"; // replace with the profile you want to show
File profileDir = makeAndGetProfileDirectory(profileName);
File profilePictureFile = new File(profileDir, "picture.jpg");

// now use Picasso to read it
Picasso.with(context)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
       .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
       .load(profilePictureFile)
       .into(imageView);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. But I am still not clear how to store the image in internal storage. I will try the following code snippet:`File myImage = new File(storagePath, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

            try { 
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage); 
                outputImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out); 
                out.flush();    
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }  `

Comment: Where does the image come from? You can indeed use `FileOutputStream` to write to the file, but you need to take the image data from somewhere...

Comment: I will get the image data from bitmap object.